# How do I add Button and Paragraph under lightbox image without it being cut off?

Tags: html, css, lightbox

Hello I created a lightbox image with CSS only and I wanted to add 2 buttons and a description paragraph underneath the image (this is after you click on the image and you view in lightbox)

I got close to adding this but the problem is when the browser is not that tall the buttons and paragraph do not show and there is no option to scroll and see them.

If someone could help me out I would appreciate it.

[Lightbox CSS Only With Image & Paragraph](https://codepen.io/rubenjr005/pen/ZEWEBPo?editors=1100)

```css
// COLORS

$yellow-color: #d9b311;
$light-blue: #0080A7;
$medium-color: #ccc;
$dark-blue: #00111e;

// All Buttons will share these styles
%btn-shared {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.8rem 2rem;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


.btn {
  &-main {
    @extend %btn-shared; // Brings styles from BTN Shared
    color: #333;
    background-color: $yellow-color;
  }

  &-light {
    @extend %btn-shared; // Brings styles from BTN Shared
    color: #333;
    background-color: $light-blue;
  }

  &-dark {
    @extend %btn-shared; // Brings styles from BTN Shared
    color: #f4f4f4;
    background-color: $dark-blue;
  }
}

.p2 {
  &:hover {
    opacity: 0.3;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}


/** LIGHTBOX MARKUP **/

.lightbox {
  /** Default lightbox to hidden */
  display: none;

  /** Position and style */
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.lightbox img {
  /** Pad the lightbox image */
  max-width: 650px;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin-top: 2%;
}
.lightbox .image-button-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;

  .buttons-container {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 40px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;

    .btn-dark {
      margin: 0 1rem;
      border: 3px solid white;
    }
  }
}

.lightbox:target {
  /** Remove default browser outline */
  outline: none;

  /** Unhide lightbox **/
  display: block;
}
```

```html
        <!-- ================= Image & Lightbox ================== -->

        <!-- PHOTO BOOTH TEMPLATE KING -->

        <div class="single-content webdesign webdev grid-item">
          <a href="#img21">
            <img
              class="p2"
              src="http://ruben123.com/img/ruben-123-Portfolio-img/web-design/ruben123_Web-Design_01.jpg"
            />
          </a>
        </div>

        <!-- lightbox container hidden with CSS -->

        <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img21">
          <div class="image-button-container">
            <img
              src="http://ruben123.com/img/ruben-123-Portfolio-img/web-design/ruben123_Web-Design_01.jpg"
            />
            <!-- ======================== ****** Paragraph  Container ****** ======================== -->       
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam mollitia minus magnam, laborum quia molestiae laboriosam! Rerum adipisci architecto ex.</p>
            

            <!-- ======================== ****** Buttons Container ****** ======================== -->
            <div class="buttons-container">
              <!-- Button Download -->
              <form
                method="get"
                action="img/"
              >
                <button class="btn-dark" type="submit">Download PSD</button>
              </form>

              <!-- Visit Website -->
              <button
                class="btn-dark"
                onclick="window.location.href = 'https://photoboothtemplateking.com/';"
              >
                Visit Website
              </button>
            </div>
            <!-- ======================== ****** Buttons Container ****** ======================== -->
          </div>
        </a>
```

I am using SCSS for this project. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot is going on here regarding positioning and displaying elements but below you can see an example using overflow on the div that contains the image, the text and the buttons.

apply the next css on your `.image-button-container`

```
width: 517px;
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
overflow: auto;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
```

apply the next css on your `.lightbox img`, also remove `max-height: 100%;` and `margin-top: 2%;` from it so it can apply auto height and remove unecessary top margin.

```
width: 100%;
display: block;
```

apply the next css on your `.lightbox p`

```
display: block;
position: relative;
```

and finally apply the next css on the `.buttons-container`, also concider removign the `bottom: 40px` rule.

```
display: block;
position: relative;
```

Comment: Thank you so much I will try this tomorrow after after work.